# I wonder how to underline the wrong words in MS WORD

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I wonder how to underline the wrong words in MS WORD.
I think we should use vsto and XML.
Please let me know if you have a sample source to underline.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear what you're smoking.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'wrong' word - a spelling error?

Comment: yes, spelling error.

Comment: I wonder The principle of red lines in the spelling error

Comment: Word already underlines spelling errors for you.

Comment: I know. but I want to know how to draw underline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, you might use:

```
Dim Rng As Range
For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
  Rng.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
  Rng.Font.UnderlineColor = wdColorRed
Next
```

I'll leave you to do any adaptations.

Comment: Thank you. I know this way. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you knew this, why did you bother asking how and not say so? That is the way Word provides; if you want to do it differently, you'll have to create your own method.